# Connect 2 Javascript codes

Tags: javascript

I have 2 pieces of javascript. I tried to combine them but failed. The first piece randomly creates text and second piece replaces title text.

The problem is to create combined code such that it will replace title with text which had randomly generated. Basically connect this 2 codes :

**First Javascript :**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function init() {
    generate();

    var enterButton = document.getElementById("haikuButton");
    enterButton.addEventListener("click", generate);

}

var prevRandom;

function generate() {
    var threeS = [
    /* ------------------------------------------------------- */
        "Some text",
    /* ------------------------------------------------------- */
        "Some text 2", ];

    var rand;

    do {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * threeS.length);
    } while (rand === prevRandom);

    prevRandom = rand;
    document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = threeS[rand];
    var input = document.getElementById('id_name').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    input.value = threeS[rand];
}
```

**Second code :**

```
..
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeTitle(title) { document.title = title; }
</script>
..
<input type='button' onclick='changeTitle("new title")' value='Change Title'/>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Why not integrate both scripts into one?

Comment: I tried , but not work .

Comment: There is a `}` conspicuously missing at the end of the first function definition. Please do yourself a favour and use a code editor that can pretty print your code and point out obvious syntactical mistakes. Another good idea (because it makes this easier) is to separate out your JavaScript code into separate files as much as possible.

Comment: Connecting two codes doesn't make sense. You should be more specific.

Comment: @reinierpost: I think that might have only looked like it because of the formatting. Pasting the code into jsFiddle and hit format didn't raise any formatting issues. Didn't look like anything was missing there. I didn't add/remove anything myself.

Comment: Thanks for formatting it anyway ...

Comment: There's a comma too many - after the last element in the threeS array.  Why is there an input involved ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like perhaps you have difficulty because your *function* `generate` does not actually `return` anything; it sets things and then ends.

This means to solve your problem you could do one of the following options

- Refactor your code so `generate` returns without setting, and another (new) function sets things including the document's title.
- Add the line `changeTitle(threeS[rand])` to the end of `generate`, this requires the second script to have been loaded correctly before the first is invoked.
- Make a (new) function which **gets** the value from #id_name, say `foo` and then calls `changeTitle(foo)`

---

In *my opinion*, it would be best to refactor the code so that you have a more generic function.

```
function generate() {
    var threeS = [/* etc */], rand;
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (threeS.length - 1));
    if (rand >= prevRandom) // no loop, always a different value
        rand = (rand + 1) % threeS.length;
    prevRandom = rand;
    return threeS[rand];
}

function makeFieldsRandom() {
    var val = generate(),
        words = document.getElementById("words"),
        id_name = document.getElementById('id_name'),
        input = id_name.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    words.innerHTML = val;
    input.value = val;
    document.title = val;
}
```

Then invoke `makeFieldsRandom` instead of whatever else

Answer (score 0):

Just call the second function from the first one after rand variable is set:
http://jsbin.com/yugututa/2/edit

Comment: I am not sure jsfiddle/jsbin let you set the title (probably in both your code runs inside an iframe), but put it in your project and check - it works. Also you can put console.log(document.title) immediately after the changeTitle function call to check that it works.